# Multidimensional array in form field

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, multidimensional-array

I have form field like this:

```
<input class="form-control js-invoice-product-search" placeholder="Product" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="data[products[0][name]]">
```

As you can see, field name is 'data[products[0][name]]'.

But then I submit the form, i get result like this:

```
 ["products[0"]=>
array(3) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "test"
```

It looses bracket: "products[0"
So if i have more than one product, i get 3 different elements with different names, instead of array.

Comment: Why did you give it such complicated name?

Comment: Im trying to generate json object and put it into database. Its invoice, with its data and product list. Example 'schema':


{
  vat_number: 'something',
  currency: 'EUR',
  products: []
}

Like i said. Everything goes to column 'data' in database.

Comment: Well, I tried replicating your code and indeed, it doesn't work. You will have to get rid of brackets in 'name' and think of a solution.

Comment: I have separated products from data in form, and combine them after form submission (on server side). But anyway, this is strange behavior. I didn't find any limitations for this. Maybe it's php issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, It was ridiculously simple solution. A bit shame, that I didn't tried it.

Instead name "array[key1[nestedone]]" you just need to use 'array[key1][nested1]'.

HTML is not PHP. :)